# bloquear o enter dentro de um input

Tags: javascript, html

Galera tenho o seguinte input dentro de um form:

```
<input type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_nome' id='auto' name='verifica_nome3'>
```

Preciso bloquear a tecla enter dentro dele, ou seja, quando o cursor estiver dentro dele o enter não envia o form, porém se estiver dentro de qualquer outro input o enter pode enviar o form.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o evento para todos os inputs mas [exclua](http://api.jquery.com/not/) esse:

```js
$('input').not('#auto').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) { // se pressionar enter
        console.log('pode submeter'); // aqui pode submeter o form
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_nome' id='auto' name='verifica_nome3'>
<input type="text" placeholder="Se o cursor estiver aqui pode submeter form">
```

[EXEMPLO](http://jsfiddle.net/qm5AG/1726/) no jsfiddle

Ou ao contrário (provavelmente este adequa-se mais ao que quer):

```js
$('#auto').keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('Não vou enviar');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_nome' id='auto' name='verifica_nome3'>
<input type="text" placeholder="Se o cursor estiver aqui pode submeter form">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

[EXEMPLO](http://jsfiddle.net/qm5AG/1729/) no jsfiddle

Answer (score 3):

Você pode adicionar uma função ao seu input que não faz nada, quando o enter é apertado.

```
<input type='text' class='form_campos form_campos_nome' id='auto' name='verifica_nome3' onkeypress="doNothing()">

function doNothing() {  
  var keyCode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which ? event.which : event.charCode;
  if( keyCode == 13 ) {


  if(!e) var e = window.event;

  e.cancelBubble = true;
  e.returnValue = false;

  if (e.stopPropagation) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

se for só para travar o enter, basta fazer isso:

```
$(function() {
   $('form').submit(function(event){
       return checkFocus();
    });
 });

 function checkFocus() {
  if ($('#auto').is(':focus')) {
     return false;
  }
  return true;
 }
```

[**Aqui o exemplo funcionando**](https://jsfiddle.net/287rLwee/)